# How to store a table after evaluation and immediately use the stored table for another calculation, automatically

Tags: list-manipulation, matrix, performance-tuning

Here is a simple example of what I want to achieve. Consider the two tables table
`T1:=Table[I,{I,1,5}]` and `T2:=Table[5n,{n,1,5}]`
Now suppose I want to use this table for further calculations, say `T3:=Table[T1[[n]]*T2[[m]],{n,1,5},{m,1,5}]`
This calculation is much faster if I define new tables, being the evaluated versions of T1 and T2,i.e., `T1T:={1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`,`T2T:={5, 10, 15, 20, 25}` and instead calculate T3 as 
`T3:=Table[T1T[[n]]*T2T[[m]],{n,1,5},{m,1,5}]`. My question is, is there some way to have Mathematica do this for me automatically. That is, is there a way to define a table, then use the the evaluated version of the table to use for the next calculation? I tried using import and export functions, this definitely made it faster but not nearly as fast as manually copying and pasting the evaluated table.

Comment: Beware that the set-operator in _Mathematica_ is `=` (`Set`) and that `:=` is something else (`SetDelayed`). You definitely want to use `=` here, not `:=`.

Comment: This should also solve your performance problems...

Comment: Also, `I` is the imaginary number. Don't use capital letters as variables.

Comment: `T3 = KroneckerProduct[T1,T2]` will be faster than your table.

Comment: ```=``` is way faster, I'm such a rookie, this fixes my issue in the simplest way possible. Follow up question, how can I prevent it from printing out everything? That was why I went with set delay and thought this was the only difference.

Comment: A semicolon at the end of the line quiets the output. I recommend you have a look at a Mathematica tutorial that goes over the basic structure of the language.

Answer (score 3):

Summarizing the comments: use lowercase letters, [`Set`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Set.html)(=), and [`KroneckerProduct`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/KroneckerProduct.html),

```
T1 = Table[i, {i, 1, 5}]
(*    {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}    *)

T2 = Table[5 n, {n, 1, 5}]
(*    {5, 10, 15, 20, 25}    *)

T3 = KroneckerProduct[T1, T2]
(*    {{5, 10, 15, 20, 25},
       {10, 20, 30, 40, 50},
       {15, 30, 45, 60, 75},
       {20, 40, 60, 80, 100},
       {25, 50, 75, 100, 125}}    *)
```